# How to stream command outputs with a channel?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am trying to capture command output as it occurs so I can flush it as buffered data to an HTTP client but I am not using channels correctly and don't know how to fix it.

This is essentially how I'm implementing it. The output channel is never received and I don't get the command output. It must be something fairly obvious but I'm not seeing it.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    output := make(chan []byte, 1024)
    done := make(chan struct{})

    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello")

    go execute(cmd, output, done)

    for {
        select {
        case data := <-output:
            fmt.Println("Got data")
            fmt.Println(string(data))
            //Flush to http.ResponseWriter
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Done")
            return
        }
    }
}

func execute(cmd *exec.Cmd, output chan []byte, done chan struct{}) {
    defer func() {
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting stdout pipe: %v", err))
        return
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting stderr pipe: %v", err))
        return
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(io.MultiReader(stdout, stderr))

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error executing: %v", err))
        return
    }

    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(string(scanner.Bytes()))
            output <- scanner.Bytes()
            fmt.Println("Sent data")
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error waiting for the script to complete: %v", err))
        return
    }
}
```

EDIT:

After some thought, here is updated code. This working as I expect but still not sure if I'm doing this correctly. I removed the done channel and range over the output channel. This receives everything from the output as sent via the scanner in execute and won't block since output is closed when the command finished. This is not printing "hello" in Go Playground but I am getting expected behavior in my project.

Would still appreciate feedback.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    output := make(chan []byte)

    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello")

    go execute(cmd, output)

    for data := range output {
        fmt.Println(string(data))
    }
}

func execute(cmd *exec.Cmd, output chan []byte) {
    defer close(output)

    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting stdout pipe: %v", err))
        return
    }
    cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

    done := make(chan struct{})

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error executing: %v", err))
        return
    }

    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            output <- scanner.Bytes()
        }
        done <- struct{}{}
    }()

    <-done

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        output <- []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Error waiting for the script to complete: %v", err))
    }
}
```

Comment: The program does not guarantee that the scanner loop executes before the value is sent to `done`, nor does the program guarantee that values sent to `output` are received before a value is received from `done`.   Signal completion from the scanner loop goroutine.  Change `output` to unbuffered channel.  There may be other issues.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Updated with code that is working for me (but not in Go Playground for some reason). Instead of using a done channel, I can range over the output channel and close it when the command is finished.

Comment: Move `defer close(done)` to scanner loop goroutine to ensure that 1) the program does not panic on send to close channel and 2) the scanner loop completes sending values before `for data := range output` completes.

Comment: Not that this is the cause of any issues, but the Multireader and extra pipe for standard error is not needed.  Use `cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout` to get the combined stream of standard error and standard out through `stdout`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón If I close output in the go routine, then I won't be able to capture the error from `cmd.Wait()`. But that's better than risking a panic.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  Leave `defer close(output)` in `execute` and and code to wait for scanner loop goroutine to complete before returning from `execute`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Made some more edits. Now it blocks on the `done` channel until the scanner is finished and then I can get the` cmd.Wait()` error.

Comment: Yup, that works.

Comment: Feel free to summarize your help in an answer and I can accept it.